# Bit manipulation for __int128

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I tried to add bits to an __int128 (using clang compiler and 64-bit system), but failed.

```
__int128 x = 0;                           //DECLARING AND INITIALIZING X
x |= ((static_cast<__int128>(1)) << 95);  //ADDING A '1' TO 95th BIT (from right)
std::cerr<< std::bitset<100>(x) << std::endl;  //PRINTING BITSET
```

prints:

> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I know there are short forms I can use for unsigned int or long long int, such as
(1u << 15) or (1LL << 15), but I haven't found any 128-bit equivalent.

What do I need to do make this work?

Comment: very nice nick ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we use braces `std::bitset<100>{x}` instead of parentheses `std::bitset<100>(x)`, the program fails to compile because of a narrowing conversion:

> error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type `'__int128'` to `'unsigned long long'` in
>         initializer list `[-Wc++11-narrowing]`

What's happening here is the `__int128` is working correctly, but the conversion to `std::bitset` is incorrect.  You'll have to split the `__int128` into 64-bit chunks:

```
std::bitset<100> hi{static_cast<unsigned long long>(x >> 64)},
                 lo{static_cast<unsigned long long>(x)},
                 bits{(hi << 64) | lo};
std::cout << bits << '\n';
```

Comment: The argument makes sense.
However, when compiling with clang and use 'std::bitset<100>{x}, I get:
expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction

Comment: @GillBates The `{x}` initialization only works if you enable c++11 (or later) using `-std=c++11`.